# Ajax Rating inside Repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get CurrentRating from `ajax:Rating` inside `asp:Repeater` but it gives me 0.

My code in asp.net:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <ajax:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" StarCssClass="Star" 
        WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
        FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" OnChanged="Save_Location"></ajax:Rating>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in C# behind:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in Repeater1.Items)
{
    Rating ratingControl;
    int rate;

    ratingControl = (Rating)(rptItem.FindControl("Rating1"));
    rate = ratingControl.CurrentRating;

    if (rate != 0)
    {
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would implement your code in the Repeater DataBind event

Comment: thanks it helped me to find the solution (Y).